# Torsion in the spectral sequence for a stratified complex variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stratifications

Let $X$ be a (possibly singular) complex projective algebraic variety, endowed with a stratification $\{X_{\Delta}\}_{\Delta\in I}$ by smooth algebraic varieties.

Then there is a spectral sequence
$$E_1^{p,q}:=\bigoplus_{dim(X_{\Delta})=p}H_c^{p+q}(X_{\Delta},\mathbb Z)\Rightarrow H^{p+q}_c(X, \mathbb Z).$$
Assume that $H_c^{i}(X_{\Delta},\mathbb Z)$ and $H^{i}_c(X, \mathbb Z)$ have no torsion for every $i$.

Are there assumptions guaranteeing either that

1)$E^{p,q}_{2}$ has no torsion for every $p,q$ or

2)The spectral sequence degenerates in $E_2$?

For 2), it is not hard no find (rather strong) Hodge-theoretic conditions guaranteeing the spectral sequence degenerates in $E_2$ with rational coefficients, but with integral coefficients, I couldn't find anything in the literature.

Thank you in advance!